# How to catch a View with Tag by Espresso in Android?

Tags: android, android-espresso

I have a `PinCodeView` that extends `LinearLayout`. I have following code in my `init()` method. `DigitEditText` extends `EditText` and just accepts one digit. This view will be used to receive confirmation code which has 4 digits long.

```
private void init()
{
    ...

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        DigitEditText digitView = getDigitInput();
        digitView.setTag(R.id.etPinCodeView, i); // uses for Espresso testing
        digitView.setKeyEventCallback(this);
        ...
}
```

I have created `res/values/ids.xml` and this is its content:

```
<resources>
    <item name="etPinCodeView" type="id"/>
</resources>
```

Now, in Espresso I want to catch each `DigitEditText` and put a digit in it. How I'm able to do that? I see there are two methodes, `withTagKey()` and `withTagValue()` but I have no idea how to get them into work.

I thought something like this might work but seems I'm not able to assign 0 into `withTagValue()`.

```
onView(allOf(withTagKey(R.id.etPinCodeView), withTagValue(matches(0)))).perform(typeText("2"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with this trick. Hope it saves some times for you.

First I used `Id` rather than `tag`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        DigitEditText digitView = getDigitInput();
        digitView.setId(R.id.etPinCodeView + i); // uses for Espresso testing
        digitView.setKeyEventCallback(this);
        ...
```

And this is test for it:

```
onView(withId(R.id.etPinCodeView + 0)).perform(typeText("2"));
onView(withId(R.id.etPinCodeView + 1)).perform(typeText("0"));
onView(withId(R.id.etPinCodeView + 2)).perform(typeText("1"));
onView(withId(R.id.etPinCodeView + 3)).perform(typeText("6"));
```

Comment: Why are you using a matcher of withId(...) instead of withTagValue(...) in your test while you are setting a tag setTag(...) in your init() method?

Answer (score 30):

Since [`withTagValue`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/matcher/ViewMatchers.html#withTagValue(org.hamcrest.Matcher%3Cjava.lang.Object%3E)) needs an instance of `org.hamcrest.Matcher` as an argument, we can create a simple one using the [`Matcher.is`](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#is(T)) method
to find views with a certain tag in your expresso test:

```
String tagValue = "lorem impsum";
ViewInteraction viewWithTagVI = onView(withTagValue(is((Object) tagValue)));
```

Comment: where `is` available , I'm not able to find it

Comment: @LavekushAgrawal,  Thanks for your comment.   I improved my answer with links and better explanation.

Comment: I needed:
``onView(withTagValue(Matchers.`is`(object)))``

Comment: @hmac  check you imports.  this answer does what you need.  check your imports lines if your file is missing access to `is`

Answer (score 7):

After setting the tag in your view somewhere in the app, for those confused about the syntax in **Kotlin**:

```
withTagValue(`is`(EXPECTED_TAG))
```

The complete syntax to assert a tag on a specific view:

```
onView(
   allOf(
       withId(R.id.some_id),
       withTagValue(`is`(EXPECTED_TAG))
   )
)
```

Simple :)

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this myself recently, and there is a second form of `withTagKey` which also includes a matcher for the value.  For your case, I think the right code would be:

```
onView(withTagKey(R.id.etPinCodeView,is(equalTo(0)))).perform(typeText("2"));
```