# What to do in Espresso when the recyclerView itself returns AmbiguousViewMatcherException?

Tags: java, android, automated-tests, kotlin, android-espresso

The problem is that I have a tabbed view, and each page contains the same recyclerView with different data pertaining to that tab. If I'm not describing it too well, it's essentially the same as described in this tutorial: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/ViewPager-with-FragmentPagerAdapter

I am creating instrumentation tests using Espresso, and when I try to call

```
onView(withId(R.id.recycler_view)
```

to use with a RecyclerViewAction, I am returned the AmbiguousViewMatcher telling me there is more than one recyclerView in the hierarchy. How can I specify a particular recyclerView? I assume that I will need a 'customRecyclerViewMatcher' of some sort

Comment: Check this answer [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36945219/espresso-recyclerview-inside-viewpager/37157492#37157492](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36945219/espresso-recyclerview-inside-viewpager/37157492#37157492)

Comment: This would be great, if the item I want to click was on screen when the activity is launched... unfortunately in this instance I need to scroll down to the item first

Answer (score 0):

ok! So first I needed to give each view a tag 
(see petey's answer for [How to catch a View with Tag by Espresso in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35675296/how-to-catch-a-view-with-tag-by-espresso-in-android))

I found the onCreate and added:

```
recyclerView.setTag(screenTab.getId())
```

Which enabled me to set this within my test class (fyi I'm using Kotlin)

```
  private val tab1RecyclerView = onView(
      allOf(
          withId(R.id.recycler_view),
          withTagValue(`is`(Id.tab1))
      )
  )
```

so that my tests begin like this :

```
@Test
fun tab1Test() {
tab1RecyclerView.perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition... etc
}
```