# How to get the tag of a view in an Espresso test?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-espresso, end-to-end, uitest

I am working in some end to end test using Espresso.
In the test I need to know the user id (because I need to call one endpoint that mocks some external party).
To get the user id, I was thinking about setting it as a tag in a view and get the tag with Espresso.

Is there a way to do that?

I only find ways to [get a view by tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35675296/how-to-catch-a-view-with-tag-by-espresso-in-android), but not actually getting the content of the tag.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following extension function:

```
inline fun <reified T : Any> ViewInteraction.getTag(): T? {
    var tag: T? = null
    perform(object : ViewAction {
        override fun getConstraints() = ViewMatchers.isAssignableFrom(View::class.java)

        override fun getDescription() = "Get tag from View"

        override fun perform(uiController: UiController, view: View) {
            when (val viewTag = view.tag) {
                is T -> tag = viewTag
                else -> error("The tag cannot be casted to the given type!")
            }
        }
    })
    return tag
}
```

To the get tag like:

```
@Test
fun myTest() {
    ...
    val userId = onView(withId(R.id.myView)).getTag<String>()
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need **Espresso** to retrieve a `View` tag - instead, you could simply call `findViewById(...)` to find your `View` and then retrieve its tag using `getTag()` method.

So, assuming, you use `ActivityTestRule` to launch your `Activity`, `View` is visible and has a unique ID within the `Activity`, you could do it as follows:

```
...
// make sure the View is there and visible
onView(withId(R.id.someId)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));

// retrieve its tag using ActivityTestRule
String tag = (String) activityRule.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.someId).getTag();
...
```